# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed. How to fix this?

Tags: java, linux, caching, jasperserver

I'm uploading a xls sheet to my website that is supposed to create a pdf. But it throws the mentioned exception with the following stack trace :-

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:73)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadImage(JRImageLoader.java:245)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getImage(JRImageRenderer.java:476)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getOnErrorRendererForImage(JRImageRenderer.java:429)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1298)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:773)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:737)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:615)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:384)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:122)

I tried googling for the fix regarding jasperreports and it seems like some issue with the images/logos. The other answers were suggesting to set 'using cache = true' somewhere and I couldn't understand where and how to use it.